# How to change Android MediaCodec video orientation

Tags: android, video, android-camera, wowza, libstreaming

I'm using libstreaming (https://github.com/fyhertz/libstreaming) for my live video streaming but the orientation of the video is always in landscape orientation at the receiver(server) side. I tried rotating my byte using the  rotateYUV420Degree90(data,mQuality.resX,mQuality.resY) but the issue has not solved. I'm attaching the code used the libstreaming library for converting the byte below.

```
 public byte[] convert(byte[] data) {

    // A buffer large enough for every case
    if (mBuffer==null || mBuffer.length != 3*mSliceHeight*mStride/2+mYPadding) {
        mBuffer = new byte[3*mSliceHeight*mStride/2+mYPadding];
    }

    if (!mPlanar) {
        if (mSliceHeight==mHeight && mStride==mWidth) {
            // Swaps U and V
            if (!mPanesReversed) {
                for (int i = mSize; i < mSize+mSize/2; i += 2) {
                    mBuffer[0] = data[i+1];
                    data[i+1] = data[i];
                    data[i] = mBuffer[0]; 
                }
            }
            if (mYPadding>0) {
                System.arraycopy(data, 0, mBuffer, 0, mSize);
                System.arraycopy(data, mSize, mBuffer, mSize+mYPadding, mSize/2);
                return mBuffer;
            }
            return data;
        }
    } else {
        if (mSliceHeight==mHeight && mStride==mWidth) {
            // De-interleave U and V
            if (!mPanesReversed) {
                for (int i = 0; i < mSize/4; i+=1) {
                    mBuffer[i] = data[mSize+2*i+1];
                    mBuffer[mSize/4+i] = data[mSize+2*i];
                }
            } else {
                for (int i = 0; i < mSize/4; i+=1) {
                    mBuffer[i] = data[mSize+2*i];
                    mBuffer[mSize/4+i] = data[mSize+2*i+1];
                }
            }
            if (mYPadding == 0) {
                System.arraycopy(mBuffer, 0, data, mSize, mSize/2);
            } else {
                System.arraycopy(data, 0, mBuffer, 0, mSize);
                System.arraycopy(mBuffer, 0, mBuffer, mSize+mYPadding, mSize/2);
                return mBuffer;
            }
            return data;
        }
    }

    return data;
}
```

Is there any way to handle the camera orientation or the recorded video orientation. Please do help me resolve the issue.

Comment: Is _[this](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/562cb77c-6fca-4c80-aa2f-aaddac289efa/)_ your rotation method? You say that it did not solve the orientation problem with Wowza server. Did it have any effect at all? What is the relation of all this to **convert()** method you posted?

Comment: @AlexCohn I got this method from a stackoverflow question. I use the libstreaming library for video streaming. It is a known issue https://github.com/fyhertz/libstreaming/issues/36

Comment: You probably missed my reply on [that thread](https://github.com/fyhertz/libstreaming/issues/36)